# Use an If statement with the button name in Objective-C (Cocoa/iPhone SDK)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have to implement a small feature in an iPhone app and was wondering if there was a way to do use an **if** statement where the condition is the string of a button.

Here’s a sample of the code in question:

```
- (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender{  
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if ( button.titleLabel.text == “SomeText” )
{
   //do something
}
else
{
   // some other thing
}
```

Now I can’t make it work, because I think I’m using the wrong code in button.titleLabel.text. I’ve even tried @“SomeText”), but I always end up in //some other thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently doing is comparing two pointers to objects, the objects `button.titleLabel.text` and `@"SomeText"`. As both point to different places in the memory, the comparison will return `NO`.

If you want to compare the **values** of both `NSString` objects, however, you can use `[button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"SomeText"]`.

Also note that `"SomeText"` is not the same as `@"SomeText"`! The first is a regular C string, where the last one is a Cocoa `NSString` object.

Comment: Thanks Douwe, too much C# here ;) my C/C++ knowledge was buried under a layer of many years of .NET/Java.